# Xamarin App running in Ios simulator using visual studio

Tags: ios, xcode, xamarin

I am facing the issue to run the xamarin app in IOS simulator. Whenever i am trying to run this app it was asking me to add or pair the Mac. Since I dont own the Mac I tried to install Xamarin.Ios in windows. In this process i need to install the XCode in my windows 10 Os. First of all i am unable to download the Xcode tool from Apple portal with valid credentials. I followed the below 2 links but no luck to download and install the Xcode. Could you guys please help me the easiest solution to download install the Xcode to do the next level of run the App in windows.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/windows/?pivots=windows

https://apps.apple.com/us/app/xcode/id497799835?mt=12

Comment: Xcode only runs on macOS

Comment: So do we have any other option to run the xamarin app pointing to IOS using VS in windows10.

Comment: You need to have a mac to run Xamarin.iOS project in windows.

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT - Can we do it through any VM which contains Mac?

Comment: There is a tip in the document you shared: If you do not have access to a Mac, you can use MacinCloud or MacStadium; both services provide cloud-based Mac hardware that you can use to build Xamarin.iOS projects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bottom line is that iOS apps must be build using a licensed Mac OS, period. Visual Studio for Windows does not actually build the iOS app, what it does do is connect to a Mac (which must have XCode installed) and facilitate a remote iOS build via XCode. However, if you have a Mac, you can build both iOS and Android code directly on your Mac using Visual Studio for Mac. Yes, it is frustrating that you must have access to a Mac OS to build iOS apps, but this is a requirement and there is no way around it.